# Object error while importing a site package in Kentico 9

Tags: kentico

I have 30 days license for Kentico 9.

I import a site packgae and I get below error

"Order objects cannot be imported due to license limitations. License for feature 'Ecommerce' not found."

Can't I import a site package if I have limited days license or is this error something else ?

Comment: Wait, are you trying to bypass the license limitations? It's clear in the error message you can't import those objects _because_ you have a 30 day license.

Answer (score 1):

You can't import ecommerce website into the free license version, but you have fresh Kentico installation you are able to use trial EMS license for localhost domain.